# Iframe оплата от Яндекса

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Есть кнопка от Яндекса по оплате (в iframe).
http://test2.mobile99.ru/handler.php

Мне надо чтобы сумма в нее подставлялась в зависимости от того, что выбрал пользователь на предыдущей странице. Как мне достучаться из своей страницы в value инпута, (который грузится из Яндекса).

Никак не могу понять, как мне управлять из своего окна документом во фрейме, который грузится из яндекса.

Comment: как вариант выставить параметр `default-sum=` но проще посмотреть описание api, и узнать какие параметры за что отвечают

Comment: сумму по дефолту я мог бы и в конструкторе кнопки выставить, у меня должны быть разные суммы попадать туда. я не пойму как мне достучаться до инпута

Answer (score 0):

То что будет выведено в iframe настраивается за счет get параметров. Изменив один параметр можно получить другую форму.

За заполнения инпута с суммой отвечает параметр `default-sum`. Странно, но о нем не нашел упоминаний в [справке](https://money.yandex.ru/doc.xml?id=526991)

То есть, при изменении этого параметра произойдет перезагрузка iframe и в окне будет выведено нужное число.

Пример:

```js
var urlString = "https://money.yandex.ru/quickpay/shop-widget?account=4100xxxxx&quickpay=shop&payment-type-choice=on&mobile-payment-type-choice=on&writer=seller&targets=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA&targets-hint=&button-text=01&successURL=";

document.getElementById('b').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var value = document.getElementById('val').value;
  var url = new URL(urlString);
  url.searchParams.append('default-sum', value);
  document.getElementById('ya').src = url.toString();
});
```

```html
<input id="val"><button id="b">Change value</button>
<iframe id="ya" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" src="https://money.yandex.ru/quickpay/shop-widget?account=41001153536181&quickpay=shop&payment-type-choice=on&mobile-payment-type-choice=on&writer=seller&targets=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA&targets-hint=&button-text=01&successURL="
  width="450" height="198"></iframe>
```